# JMeter CSV Data Config choosing different rows for different Threads

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have n number of threads  for my JMeter test pack  .
The threads need to pick a value from the parameter (.csv) file and execute for 'x' number of times with the same value .
How can I make the threads choose different rows from the .csv file and retain the same for execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the following setup:

- thread 1 always using line 1 from the CSV file
- thread 2 always using line 2 from the CSV file
- etc.

the easiest way is using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)}
```

[image]

where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) and `ctx.getThreadNum()` function returns the number of current thread (virtual user), see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details on using this and other JMeter API shortcuts